# How can I plot two different variables from the same column in Altair?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-analysis, altair

A very newbie question but very new in using Altair library. I have Dates as X-axis and and in Y column containing 0 and 1. I want two lines one for 0 and one for 1 both of different colours. How to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by mapping this column to the color encoding. Here's a short example:

```python
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', freq='D', periods=10),
    'y': np.random.randn(10).cumsum(),
    'z': np.random.randint(0, 2, 10),
})

alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x='x:T',
    y='y:Q',
    color='z:O'
)
```

[image]